# How to create a 3 second delay using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create a 3 second delay for the following class: .mag-megamenu .dropdown.mag-megamenu-fw .dropdown-menu

I would like to use the solution found here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943704/3684265

However I'm having an issue finding the correct hover class to apply the visibility and opacity styles to. I have applied visibility, opacity and transition to .mag-megamenu .dropdown.mag-megamenu-fw which works to hide it the drop down, but when I hover over the main navigation items the dropdown doesn't appear.

Full stylesheet is below for reference:

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown a, .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #656565;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        padding: 6px 15px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .navbar-nav > li  .dropdown-menu {
        border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

    }
    .mag-megamenu i {
        color: #bfbfbf;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        margin-top: 0;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu {
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding: 0;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .form-control {
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .btn {
        margin: 10px 0 20px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu video {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .mag-megamenu iframe, .mag-megamenu embed, .mag-megamenu object {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu .withoutdesc {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mag-megamenu a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu .withoutdesc ul li {
        padding: 3px 10px;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu .withoutdesc ul li:hover, .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu .withoutdesc ul li:focus {
        background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
        color: #262626;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu .withoutdesc li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0 solid #fff;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .mag-megamenu-content.withdesc a::after {
        color: #cfcfcf;
        content: attr(data-description);
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        left: 100%;
        margin-left: -1px;
        margin-top: 0;
        top: 0;
        transition-delay: 2s;

    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu > a::after {
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #cccccc;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        height: 0;
        margin-right: -10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 0;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu:hover > a::after {
        border-left-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu p {
        color: #656565;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .nav, .mag-megamenu .collapse, .mag-megamenu .dropup, .mag-megamenu .dropdown {
        position: static;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .half {
        left: auto !important;
        right: auto !important;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown-menu {
        left: auto;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .nav.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .mag-megamenu-content {
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown.mag-megamenu-fw .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0 !important;
        right: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 9999;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: visibility 0s, opacity 3s linear;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .dropdown.mag-megamenu-fw {
        position: initial !important;
    }
    .mag-megamenu .title {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .mag-megamenu ul {
        list-style: outside none none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .mag-megamenu ul > li {
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }

    .mag-megamenu .navbar-nav > li .dropdown-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.dropdown-menu.fullwidth li.mag-megamenu-content ul {
        display: block !important;
    }

    ul.dropdown-menu.fullwidth li.mag-megamenu-content ul li{
        font-weight: 400;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .label {    
        padding: 3px 10px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        border-radius: 2px;
        &-info {
            border: 1px solid #d9534f;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #d9534f;
        }
        &-danger {
            border: 1px solid #ffbb20;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #ffbb20;
        }
        &-success {
            border: 1px solid #5cb85c;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
        }
    }
}

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {

    .mag-megamenu .mag-megamenu-content {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    ul.dropdown-menu.fullwidth li.ui-menu-item.all-category {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: @Phix What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Ideally a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet), but there's also jsfiddle.net, stackblitz.com, codepen.io